# i didn t get the result in my simple javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, calculator

i m trying to make a simple calculator by javascript ,and i didnt get anything  in textbox result.

```html
    <html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function sum()
                    {
                  var x1 = document.getElementById("text1");
                  var x2 = document.getElementById("text2");
                  var y  = document.getElementById("text3");
                    
                  var sum = parseFloat(x1) + parseFloat(x2);
                        
                        y.value = "the result is, " + sum; 
                    }
                
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <form>
                <fieldset style="width : 100px ;text-align: center; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
                    <legend> sum +++ +++ calculator</legend>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="tap first number" id="text1"><br>
                    
                    <input type="text" placeholder="tap second number" id="text2"><br>
                    
                    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="sum()"><br>
                    
                    <input type="text" placeholder="result" id="text3"><br>
                      </fieldset>
                </form>  
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your x1 and x2 refer to the input box rather than to the value. Change to:

```
var x1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
var x2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are never getting values from text field.

Check below:

```js
 function sum() {
   var x1 = document.getElementById("text1");
   var x2 = document.getElementById("text2");
   var y = document.getElementById("text3");

   var sum = parseFloat(x1.value) + parseFloat(x2.value);

   y.value = "the result is, " + sum;
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset style="width : 100px ;text-align: center; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
    <legend> sum +++ +++ calculator</legend>
    <input type="text" placeholder="tap first number" id="text1">
    <br>

    <input type="text" placeholder="tap second number" id="text2">
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="sum()">
    <br>

    <input type="text" placeholder="result" id="text3">
    <br>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Hope it helps you.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function sum()
                    {
                  var x1 = document.getElementById("text1");
                  var x2 = document.getElementById("text2");
                  var y  = document.getElementById("text3");
                    
                  var sum = parseFloat(x1.value) + parseFloat(x2.value);
                
                        
                        y.value = "the result is, " + sum; 
                    }
                
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <form>
                <fieldset style="width : 100px ;text-align: center; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
                    <legend> sum +++ +++ calculator</legend>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="tap first number" id="text1"><br>
                    
                    <input type="text" placeholder="tap second number" id="text2"><br>
                    
                    <input type="button" value="=" onclick="sum()"><br>
                    
                    <input type="text" placeholder="result" id="text3"><br>
                      </fieldset>
                </form>  
            </body>
        </html>
```